# Im using Microsoft visual studio express 2012 and for some reason my vector is not being identified

Tags: c++, vector

This is exactly what it says on my screen 
I am asking for the size of the code and its coming back with these errors

```
2   IntelliSense: expected a '{'    c:\Users\atl\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp  11  1   ConsoleApplication3
```

Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';' c:\users\atl\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp  11  1   ConsoleApplication3

`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ vector <int> vec (3,100);
cout<<"vector one ="<<vec.size<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't valid C++:

```
int main() int _tmain
```

You're missing a semicolon after `int main();`